# Laravel, registration and login on same page. Errors on both forms

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm working on a website with Laravel and I have the registration and login forms on the same page. The only problem is that if I type the wrong password on the login form the error will show on both forms below the password input.

I've googled this and I have seen some other people with this problem but they are all working on a version below 5.4 and all those solutions are different in version 5.4. Does anyone know what exactly I need to change to make this work?
So far I've changed the names in the forms to 'login_password' and 'register_password', but this only gives me errors.

Comment: If the below post has answered your question **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to go down the route of changing the input names you'll need to update your `LoginController` and `RegisterController`.

**Login Controller**

You will need to add the following:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required', 'login_password' => 'required',
    ]);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return [
        $this->username() => $request->input($this->username()),
        'password'        => $request->input('login_password'),
    ];
}
```

**RegisterController** (these methods should already exist in the controller, you'll just need to update `password` to `register_password` where applicable)

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'register_password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['register_password']),
    ]);
}
```

You will also need to include the `Request` by putting the following at the top of the file with the other `use` statements:

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Hope this helps!